# Send empty response with fiber

Tags: rest, go, go-fiber

I'm building an API, I can't figure out how to return an empty response if most of them are like:

```
func GetEntityInstance(c *fiber.Ctx) error {

    ...

    return c.Status(fiber.StatusCreated).JSON(fiber.Map{
        "id_created": new_id,
    })
}
```

How can I send an empty body response?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As simple as it gets:

```
func main() {
    app := fiber.New()

    app.Get("/", func(c *fiber.Ctx) error {
        return c.Send(nil)
    })

    app.Listen(":5000")
}
```

You can aslo do `return c.SendStatus(http.StatusAccepted)`

Comment: Actually, `c.SendStatus(http.StatusAccepted)` would not achieve the same effect. This is not true. According to [fiber documentation](https://docs.gofiber.io/api/ctx#sendstatus), in this case the body would be the text "Status Accepted".